# How to format currency as you type using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to `<input type="number" />` when user type it, it automatically add `<span class="t"></span>` for every even-positioned thousand, for example:

```
1234567890
```

it should transforms into:

```
<span class="t">1</span>234<span class="t">567</span>890
```

I already have the code to do the formatting:

```
function N(n) {
  n = +n;
  if(!n) return '<i>0</i>';
  var str = '';
  var odd = false;
  while(n>0) {
    var rem = n % 1000;
    n = Math.floor(n / 1000)|0;
    rem = ((n) ? (P0(rem,3)) : rem);
    if(odd) rem = '<span class="n">' + rem + '</span>';
    str = rem + str;
    odd = !odd;
  }
  return str;
}
```

and the css:

```
span.n {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
```

now the problem is, how to render that html into the `input` itself, so that every changes to that `input` (when user cut, paste, doing keypress, dragging certain substring using mouse) it would rendered correctly as HTML on that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AutoNumeric](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric), a zero dependency JS plugin

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the html could be rendered properly in normal html input tag. At least not like you should expect to. Later on it will be difficult to parse.

Why don't you use either jQuery plugin like [jquery currency](https://github.com/gilbitron/jQuery-Currency)? (Assuming that you added a tag "jQuery" in your question)

Then your code will be simple as that, no hassle:

```
<input type="number" class="currency"/>
<script>
    $('input.currency').currency(); //add some options if you want to change the formatting
</script>
```